# HABTM query, return records with no associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an HABTM relationship between two tables spots and tags.  I can find all of the spots with a given set of tags using the following query:

```
ids = [2, 3, 4, 8]
s = Spot.all(:include => 'tags', :conditions => ["tags.id in (?)", ids])
```

How would I find all spots that have no tags?  I know I probably need to do a count on tags but I can't figure out how to do it.  Something like:

```
s = Spot.all(:include => 'tags', :conditions => "tags.count = 0")
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll need a left join and find those whose `spots_tags.spot_id` are NULL:

```
s = Spot.joins('LEFT JOIN spots_tags ON spots.id = spots_tags.spot_id').
         where('spots_tags.spot_id IS NULL').all
```

You can do this with a group by and count as well, but that query will be slightly more complex to build and comprehend.