# HABTM orphaned records - active record query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Rails 3:
I have an HABTM relationship between a product model and ingredient model.  I have a bunch of orphaned ingredients that I would like to delete from the database, so I need to query these ingredients in order to delete them.  Im guessing there is an easy way to do this. Can someone help me out here?  I expected this to work, but Im getting an undefined-column error

```
Ingredient.joins(:products).where(products: [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411983/habtm-query-return-records-with-no-associations)

Note that the SQL query is doing a left JOIN on the join table, in this case 'product_ingredients'

```
Ingredient.joins('LEFT JOIN product_ingredients ON ingredients.id = product_ingredients.ingredient_id').where('product_ingredients.ingredient_id IS NULL').all
```

Answer (score 1):

`products` is most likely not a columns either of your tables. I think that something like this would work (assuming that a product has a `name`, otherwise replace with any one column that actually does exist):

```
Ingredient.joins(:products).where("products.name IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ingredient.all.map { | ingredient | ingredient.products.empty? }
```

This should map all Ingredients that have that empty relation. You could also try:

```
Ingredient.all.map { | ingredient | ingredient.products.count > 0 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Loading the entire ingredient object set is too slow. Thanks for replying.